# PHP/PDO how to insert a FOR loop in the execute(array) definition?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, pdo

I am developing an Android App and I have to write my own API in php. Unfortunately, I have very little experience in PHP/mysql and API's so Im struggling.

I dont know how many pictures Im going to send to the api, so Im using a FOR loop, but Idont know how to incorporate that FOR loop inside the array definition as shown on the image:

[image]

Here is the code for your convenience:

```
            try {
                $query_add_item_photos = "INSERT INTO 

                                            product_photos (
                                                product_id, 
                                                product_photo, 
                                                product_photo_added_by_user
                                                                        ) 
                                            VALUES (

                                                :product_id, 
                                                :product_photo_main, 
                                                :product_photo_added_by_user
                                                                            )"; 

                                            for($x = 1; $x<=count($item_photo_path); $x++) {
                                                $query_add_item_photos+= ",
                                                    (

                                                        :product_id, 
                                                        :product_photo_" . $x .", 
                                                        :product_photo_added_by_user
                                                                                    )";
                                            }

                $sth = $connection->prepare($query_add_item_photos);
                $sth->execute(
                            array(
                                  ':product_id'                     => $item_id,
                                  ':product_photo_main'             => $item_main_photo_path,
                                  ':product_photo_' .$x             => $item_photo_path[$x],
                                  ':product_photo_added_by_user'    => $user_id
                                                                                                ));
```

EDIT: $product_photo_main is an image that Im obtaining in another way.

EDIT: $X'S value is always going to be between 1 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the array outside of the `execute()` method call and then pass it in as an argument. For example, something like this:

```
$array = array(
  ':product_id' => $item_id,
  ':product_photo_main' => $item_main_photo_path,
  ':product_photo_added_by_user' => $user_id,
);

foreach ($item_photo_path as $key => $path)
{
  $query_add_item_photos += ", (
    :product_id, 
    :product_photo_" . $key .", 
    :product_photo_added_by_user
  )";

  $array[':product_photo_' . $key] = $path;
}

$sth = $connection->prepare($query_add_item_photos);
$sth->execute($array);
```

Comment: this looks promising, only I dont understand the purpose of the $path variable

Comment: It's just a bit shorter to use a `foreach($array as $key => $value) { /* $key = $x, $value = $item_photo_path[$x] in your example */ }` then to use a `for()` loop and track the `$x++`/`$item_photo_path[$x]`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make your array of input parameters before call the `$sth->execute`, then you can loop through the `$item_photo_path` items and add them to the array.
Something like that:

```
$arr_input_parms = array(
    ':product_id'                     => $item_id,
    ':product_photo_main'             => $item_main_photo_path,
    ':product_photo_added_by_user'    => $user_id
);
for($x = 1; $x<=count($item_photo_path); $x++) {
    $arr_input_parms[':product_photo_' . $x] = $item_photo_path[$x];
}
$sth->execute($arr_input_parms);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but if you got such multiple stuff to insert in single column, you could first make an array of those items and than `serialize()` or `json_encode()` it to insert as a string; in that way you will not need `for` loop in `$sth->execute()` array.

Comment: I would discourage including mixed serialized data among non-serialized columns. It's a shortcut that will almost immediately lead to regret.

Comment: As far as I know, `unserialize()` may be a security issue if you got it from untrusted source. I'll appreciate if you could share a link or useful examples of issues.

Comment: Well, you can't query against serialized data (e.g. query conditions, joins). If your data model changes at all you'll have to write a script that runs through all records, unserializes all data, adjusts the data model, and inserts/updates accordingly. This has a lot of overhead. On the flipside, there are some really interesting points brought up in this blog post and comments about using MySQL to store serialized objects: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/21/when-should-you-store-serialized-objects-in-the-database/